# React: call custom hook from useEffect or run code before component mounts

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit reluctant to even ask this but here goes...

I have a custom hook useScript based off [this implementation](https://usehooks.com/useScript/) but I want to call it from `useEffect` so that it runs before the component mounts but according to the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) I know I can't do that.

The issue is that I want to delay rendering my component until the script has loaded but I have no way to set state without causing a 'Too many re-renders' Error.

Here are two options I have tried that do NOT work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // Cannot call another hook from inside useEffect
    useScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/3.9.7/typescript.min.js');
  }, []);
```

and

```
  const myComponent = (scripts) => {

    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

    scripts.forEach(script => {
      useScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typescript/3.9.7/typescript.min.js');
    });

    // where can I call setLoaded ??

    return (loaded && <div>some content</div>);
  };
```

This should be simple; What am I forgetting???

Comment: hi, please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

One approach is for a hook to return a function that executes some functionality.

So instead of:

```js
function useScript() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  // load the script...

  return [isLoaded]
}
```

You can do:

```js
function useLoadScript() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const loadScript = () => {
    // load the script...
  }

  return [isLoaded, loadScript]
}
```

So that the functionality can be consumed within another hook:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const [isLoaded, loadScript] = useLoadScript()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadScript()
    // ...
  }, [])

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  return (
    // ...
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. It's a good idea but after trying this it does not suit my needs. Part of my problem is that I want to run the hook for an array of values which I know you should not do (according to the rules of Hooks) so I need to rewrite the hook to accept an array, which I have done but it's not working as expected. I moved this issue down on my backlog after being stuck on it for so long but I will come back to it and this thread if I find a working solution. Thanks @bsapaka